# ONNX Runtime: If no GPU, gracefully use CPU instead?

Tags: windows, onnxruntime

I've only used ORT for CPU.  It looks like there is a separate NuGet package for the ORT for GPU.  If I use the GPU version, if there is no GPU on the machine its running on, will it "Gracefully" run on CPU instead?  I would think almost everyone deploying an application (on the edge) would want this behaviour -- use the GPU is the user's machine has one, else use CPU.  Have they set it up this way?